# Entity Framework Migrations giving the following error: context has changed since the database was created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have implemented a small change in the Entity Framework Migrations, I have created many to many relationship, I have 3 tables which were there before but Table1 and Table2 should have many to many relationships so there is table 3 to handle this association, all these 3 tables were created before and data was going back and forth but the relationship didn't exist, so I created the relationship, using Entity Framework - now I want to check how can I execute the migrations. Do I need to run the migration on my New-get Package Manager Console etc, what commands do I need to run?

I am getting the following error: The model backing the 'IMSContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Any help please thank you.

Comment: I think you should check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli but basically the command that are you looking for is: Update-Database from the package manager

Comment: Yes I tried that link when I ran the following command, I am getting in the below: PM> add-migration Violation-OneToMany-Relationship
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'IMS.Web'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration). I have Entity Framework migrations enabled.